# Morris.js xKey adding nonsense values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, morris.js

I have been struggling with this issue for an hour, and I can't figure out why Morris chart put some kind of time values into the X axe.

First of all, my JSON is the following:

```
{"data":[{"date":"2015-06-08","payed":"18.08","to_pay":"18.08"},
         {"date":"2015-06-11","payed":"70.24","to_pay":"108.24"}]}
```

And I'm creating the chart this way:

```
var json = JSON.parse(response);

Morris.Line({
    element: 'recebimentos-chart',
    data: json.data,
    xkey: 'date',
    ykeys: ['to_pay', 'payed'],
    labels: ['To pay', 'Payed'],
    gridTextColor: '#000',
    lineColors: ['#EA8A67', '#22aa22'],
});
```

And now the problem: why in god's heaven is the X axe writing the values that the image shows?
[image]

As you can see in my JSON there's two different dates. If I only have one date (no matter which one) the chart works good (it output in the X axe the date value), for example:

```
{"data":[{"date":"2015-06-11","payed":"18.08","to_pay":"18.08"},
         {"date":"2015-06-11","payed":"70.24","to_pay":"108.24"}]}
```

**EDIT 1**: While trying in **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z97z2Lam/)** I found out that the problem is the width of the chart. With a small width the chart presents the dates correctly, with a large width it presents hours (??)

The problem is that I need to present a large chart..

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :
http://jsfiddle.net/z97z2Lam/1/

Their [doc](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html) says about the `xLabels` property:

> ```
> Sets the x axis labelling interval. By default the interval will be automatically computed. The following are valid interval strings:
> "decade"
> "year"
> "month"
> "week"
> "day"
> "hour"
> "30min"
> "15min"
> "10min"
> "5min"
> "minute"
> "30sec"
> "15sec"
> "10sec"
> "5sec"
> "second"
> ```

Comment: Your answer is correct and I will accept it.  Also, I was going to answer my question by saying that adding the setting "parseTime: false" also solves the problem. Thank you.